# once("child_added") on non existing node does not fail but timeout

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

First I'm not sure that there is a real problem but I guess I'll share my reasoning.

I use Firebase as a database / backend for the archiving of all the data from various sensors at home and an UI with cool graphs in hosting. So every 10 minutes I push various data (temperature, humidity, CO2 level, illumination, ...) coming from various rooms. I have almost 3 years of data available (so my base has a lots of nodes)

So my database structure is like that :

```
root
  readings
    room_id
      GUID
        time
        temp
        hum
        lum
```

For a few years I had a PHP script hosted at home that checked if the latest item inside each readings/room_id has a time value that is not too old (no more than 11 minutes old). I translated it to Firebase cloud function some days ago and I got something like this :

```
exports.monitor = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const tstamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
  var sensors = ["r01", "r02", "r03", "r04", "r05"];
  var promiseArray = [];
  var result = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < sensors.length; i++) {
    console.log('Adding promise for ' + sensors[i]);
    promiseArray.push(admin.database().ref('/readings/' + sensors[i]).limitToLast(1).once("child_added"));
  }
  Promise.all(promiseArray).then(snapshots => {
    console.log('All promises done : ' + snapshots.length);
    res.set('Cache-Control', 'private, max-age=300');
    for (var i = 0; i < snapshots.length; i++) {
      differenceInMinutes = (tstamp - snapshots[i].val().time) / 60;
      result[sensors[i]] = {current: tstamp,
                            sensor: snapshots[i].val().time,
                            diff: Math.round(differenceInMinutes * 10) / 10};
      if (differenceInMinutes < 11) {
        result[sensors[i]]['status'] = "OK";
      } else {
        result[sensors[i]]['status'] = "KO";
      }
    }
    return res.status(200).json(result);
  }).catch(error => {
    console.error('Error while getting sensors details', error.message);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  });
});
```

The code works well. So my question is : if I add another room ID in the sensors array that does not exists inside "readings" in my database, I thought I'll get an error (failed promise) instead I only got a huge timeout error, I don't want that kind of timeout on Firebase Cloud Functions (to avoid any unwanted cost).

Is that normal ? Is my code wrong ? Do I have to start by getting a shallow snapshot of "readings/room_id" check that it exists and check if has children ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

EDIT : With the help of Frank I fixed my code, here is the revised version :

```
exports.monitor = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const tstamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
  var sensors = ["r01", "r02", "r03", "r04", "r05"];
  var promiseArray = [];
  var result = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < sensors.length; i++) {
    console.log('Adding promise for ' + sensors[i]);
    promiseArray.push(admin.database().ref('/readings/' + sensors[i]).limitToLast(1).once("value"));
  }
  Promise.all(promiseArray).then(queryResults => {
    console.log('All promises done : ' + queryResults.length);
    res.set('Cache-Control', 'private, max-age=300');
    queryResults.forEach((snapshots, i) => {
      snapshots.forEach((snapshot) => {
        var currentData = snapshot.val();
        differenceInMinutes = (tstamp - currentData.time) / 60;
        result[sensors[i]] = {current: tstamp,
                              sensor: currentData.time,
                              diff: Math.round(differenceInMinutes * 10) / 10};
        if (differenceInMinutes < 11) {
          result[sensors[i]]['status'] = "OK";
        } else {
          result[sensors[i]]['status'] = "KO";
        }
      });
    });
    return res.status(200).json(result);
  }).catch(error => {
    console.error('Error while getting sensors details', error.message);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a `child_added` event only fires when there is a child node. If there are not child nodes under the location (or matching the query) it will *not* fire.

To ensure you also get notified in the condition there are no children, you should listen to the `value` event:

```
for (var i = 0; i < sensors.length; i++) {
  console.log('Adding promise for ' + sensors[i]);
  var query = admin.database().ref('/readings/' + sensors[i]).limitToLast(1).once("value")
  promiseArray.push(query);
}
```

Since a `value` event may match multiple children in a single snapshot (despite your query only requesting a single child), you will need to loop over the children of the resulting snapshot:

```
Promise.all(promiseArray).then((queryResults) => {
  console.log('All promises done : ' + queryResults.length);
  res.set('Cache-Control', 'private, max-age=300');
  queryResults.forEach((snapshots) => {
    snapshots.forEach((snapshot) => {
      differenceInMinutes = (tstamp - snapshot.val().time) / 60;
      ...
```

Comment: The problem I got is every "readings/room_id" has at least 150K children. Querying "readings/room_id" for "value" will get all 150K children node or am I wrong ? I don't understand what you mean by "Since a value event may match multiple children in a single snapshot"

Comment: Since you `.limitToLast(1)`, there will be only 1 result no matter if you listen for `child_added` or for `value`. But since a query *may* contain multiple results (even though it won't in this case), you will need to loop over them.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is perfect. You forgot a (snapshot) **=>** { so I modified my post to include the fixed code.

Comment: Thanks. I think I found it and fixed it. For future such mistakes, instead of including the solution in your question, just click the `edit` link and suggest an edit on my answer. That's more useful for future developers who find this post.